# QPushButton not clickable anymore with background-color style

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyside2, qpushbutton

I'm using PySide2 on my MacOS and when I add `btn.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);')` to my QPushButton the native button does not trigger the click signal anymore. How can I make the button clickable with my own custom style?

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# vim: fenc=utf-8 ts=4 sw=4 et

import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QHBoxLayout

class AppWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        btn = QPushButton('+')
        # btn.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);')
        btn.clicked.connect(lambda: print('clicked'))
        self.layout.addWidget(btn)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.resize(800, 600)
        self.setCentralWidget(AppWidget())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which results in the result shown below, a regular native button and when I click the button it prints `clicked` as expected.

[image]

When I change `# btn.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);')` to `btn.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);')` this results in the result shown below and when I click the button it does not print `clicked`

[image]

Comment: Can't reproduce (Suse Linux, Qt5.15.0, Python 3.8.3).

Comment: Works on Windows 10 Pro (2004) - PySide2 5.15 - Python 3.8.3